# How to treat warnings as errors only in selected source files (Xcode)?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, objective-c

I've started cocos2d game development and I would like to enable the flag "treat warnings as errors" in xcode, but only for the code that I write and not for all the code that is being used (ie: Cocos2D source).

The problem is that there are lots of warnings in cocos2d source code which are now being treated as errors and I do not want to mess up with this. I just want to detect warnings as errors in my code.

Is there any way to select which source code will have this flag enabled? Do I have to create different projects, each one with different flags and link with them? If so, how do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You need a custom build process

Comment: It's not very helpful but why not checkout the cocos2d source code and fix the warnings - then everyone is a bit better off ;)

Comment: It's always nice to contribute back, but that has to weighed up against the time it will take away from the project at hand. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is to add the cocos2d-iphone source code files to a separate, static library target that has "warnings as errors" turned off.

Then link your app target with the cocos2d-iphone static library by adding it under "Link Binary with Libraries" build phase.

Comment: I was going to suggest something like this. Getting to know how to build static libraries can be a useful thing in iOS development.